# DFP Ads on an AngularJS app

Tags: ajax, angularjs, google-dfp

We are building an AngularJS web app and we are trying to integrate DFP ads. By the way, we already have a PHP web app with DFP ads running so I am familiar with how DFP integration works, but of course it is different on an AngularJS app, due to its front end loading nature. So, I know there are three components we need to get working:

In the `<head>`:

- The DFP  tag for either sync or async, as shown here, https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/1651549. I know Google recommends async, but recently on our PHP app we had to switch to sync, since async doesn't support rich media, and we were also facing some reporting discrepancies with async. So, with an AngularJS app, can we still use sync, or only async?
- The DFP  tag in which we define the ad slots, and also call the enableServices, singleRequest or syncRendering, etc. By the way, we want to have dynamically populated ad slots per page (app state), so we have to figure that out.

, and in the `<body>`:

- The  tags for displaying the ads for the ad divs. On an AngularJS app would it work with .display() or would we need to call the .refresh() method?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Iraklis

Comment: We're in the exact same boat of pain.  As best I can tell the complete internet-wide absence of a way to make this work means that it's really, really hard.  It's actually mind boggling that there isn't a Google sponsored DFP directive to make this work.  So maybe that means it's impossible?  Please follow up with anything you find, as will I.

Comment: Sorry to hear you guys are struggling with it as well. We are still working on some ways of achieving this. Indeed, since they are both Google products, Google should consider making this easier. Not sure if this helps for you (I don't think it would work out of the box in our case), but there is something, https://github.com/ianmurrays/ngDfp. Good luck with your quest, we will definitely keep each other posted!

Comment: Ha, just discovered that yesterday too. It says "last commit 18 days ago", but I don't think Google indexed it until yesterday. Alas, we're trying to dynamically define ad slots as well, so it doesn't work for us either.  Back to digging..

Comment: As far as I am aware DFP sync tags use document.write... so it would be pretty hard to get that working with an angular single page app... you would have to go with a hacky solution like iframes I think.

Comment: @JGrubb did you guys find a solution for this?

Comment: We did, but it's neither pretty nor short enough to put on here.  I've been meaning to write it up, so I'll do that today and maybe it can give you some pointers.  The short answer is that you basically setup everything the opposite of a "normal" site, and then call `refresh()` on the slot(s) once they actually exist in the DOM.  Cribbed a lot of the logic from the infinite scroll example on this page as well - https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/4578089?hl=en

Comment: @JGrubb Please share your solution. I've been banging my head for two days now.

Answer (score 3):

Try this [ngDfp](https://github.com/ianmurrays/ngDfp)

ngDfp is a simple library for Angular JS that allows you to add DoubleClick for Publishers tags to your Angular site.

To show an ad, use

```
<div data-ng-dfp-ad="div-gpt-ad-1234567890123-0"></div>
```

Comment: Can I use synchronous adUnits for expandable(rich media) banners with ngDfp? How?